# Notice in phpmyadmin 5.0.1: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool, notice in Designer mode

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, erd

I'm doing some very basic database exercises in phpMyAdmin like creating tables using SQL queries and observing it in designer mode.
But I realized there is an error shown there but when I was typing the commands to create the tables, there are no mistakes. But in designer mode, there is one line in each of my tables that is in red. The notice in the designer mode says "trying to access array offset on value of type bool".
When I ignored it and proceeded to create relations to form an ERD, I can't because the line that is in red was part of the constraint.  I wonder what could be the problem. I've double-checked my queries and cross-checked the queries with my friends, drop all tables and re-create them and even re-installing xampp and phpMyAdmin. I'll add a query for one of my tables. For this particular table, the line customerName appears red in designer mode.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
CREATE TABLE customers(
`customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Works fine in phpMyAdmin 5.0.2 and Workbench

Comment: Out of interest, what version of PHP are you running on?

Comment: Oh I see hmm...I'm using xampp 7.4.1 and phpMyAdmin 4.9.5. I guess I'll try to uninstall again I guess and try installing other versions.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling my current xampp and install the newest version of xampp but the problem still persists. Hmm. I still can't figure out what could be the problem. Before this, my xampp works fine but after updating to Mac OS Catalina, it couldn't run so I followed instructions to install a new version. It works and I can run xampp and create users and modify passwords in phpMyAdmin but when I create tables and observe the designer mode, there's an error in one column in all of my tables.

Comment: Did you try MySQL Workbench

Comment: Not yet. Because for my class, I'm required to use xampp and phpmyadmin. I tried doing the constraints to link the tables in designer mode and it works now. Though one of the lines in all the tables are still red, I managed to create the constraints and link the tables. I will explore and try using Workbench too so that I can have other alternatives to phpMyAdmin